# Facing https configuration issue with Route 53 when I try to run an nginx proxy server on EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, https, amazon-eks, amazon-route53

Top of the day everyone!

I have a containerized Nginx reverse proxy server for another web server.
It has client-side & server-side caching headers configured.

To run this server on localhost HTTP 2, I have configured my server block like this using the open SSL certificates.

```
server {
    listen 443 default_server ssl http2; # IPv4
    listen [::]:443 default_server ssl http2; # IPv6

    server_name server.host.domain;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/nginx.key;
}
```

Now this works as expected on localhost, but does not work on EKS because Route53 does not expose any ssl_certificate path which I can provide to nginx.conf.

I have tried providing just the ARN from AWS to the `ssl_certificate_key` but it still fails and requires a certificate file.
This is what I get from the error logs

```
× nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2023-05-24 11:00:12 IST; 9s ago
       Docs: man:nginx(8)
    Process: 1391 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 24 11:00:11 root systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
May 24 11:00:12 root nginx[1391]: nginx: [emerg] no "ssl_certificate" is defined for the "listen ... ssl" directive in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:28
May 24 11:00:12 root nginx[1391]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
May 24 11:00:12 root systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 24 11:00:12 root systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 24 11:00:12 root systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

After going through this process, it is clear to me that we need the SSL certificate explicitly because the client-side caching and any other client-side headers do not work when I disable SSL entirely and use HTTP 1.

1. Am I missing out on any nginx configuration so that it accepts SSL credentials from Route53?
2. Do we need to purchase an external SSL certificate from Godaddy/Namecheap?

My nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes auto;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}


http {
    # Server cache zone with a maximum size of 500MB
    proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=host_cache:500m inactive=60m;

    # Set the default expiration time for cached responses to 1 hour
    proxy_cache_valid 200 1h;

    upstream my-server {
        server server.host.domain;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log error;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log combined;


    server {
        listen 443 default_server ssl http2; # IPv4
        listen [::]:443 default_server ssl http2; # IPv6

        server_name server.host.domain;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/nginx.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/nginx.key;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1.3 TLSv1.2;


        location / {
                
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow_Credentials' 'true';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Accept,Origin,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH';

            if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow_Credentials' 'true';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Accept,Origin,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
                add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                return 204;
            }


            proxy_pass https://server.host.domain;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

            # Enable client caching for 1 hour
            add_header Cache-Control "max-age=3600, public";

            # Enable server caching for 1 hour
            proxy_cache host_cache;
            proxy_cache_valid 200 60m;
            proxy_cache_valid 404 1m;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_pragma;
            proxy_cache_revalidate on;
            proxy_cache_bypass $no_cache;

            add_header X-Cached $upstream_cache_status;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For which domain was the certificate generated? It should be generated for the domain with which the server will be accessed.

Comment: So I have a domain `my-domain.com` and want to run this proxy on host-based routing like this: `proxy.my-domain.com`

Comment: In this case, one can purchase the SSL certificate for the `proxy.my-domain.com` or buy a wild card certificate for `*.my-domain.com`. 
The wild card certificates are comparatively more expensive than specific ones. Assuming you have the certificate for a specific subdomain, the configuration should include an additional `server` block with a statement pointing to that certificate. 
Ex: 
```server
{
    ... 
    server_name proxy.my-domain.com; 
    ssl_certificate <path to cert>; 
    ssl_certificate_key <path to key>;
    ...
}```

Comment: Thanks, if I get a wildcard certificate it would be for the `my-domain.com` and then all I have to do is pass it to the current server block right?

Comment: If the certificate includes `my-domain.com` along with `*.my-domain.com` then the server block would look like 
`server {     ...      server_name my-domain.com *.my-domain.com;      ssl_certificate <path to cert>;      ssl_certificate_key <path to key>;     ... }`
The essence is to include all the domains & sub-domains for which the certificate is procured for. Please bear in mind that Wild card certificates are very expensive.